# What's that tool for capturing manual changes to a Linux system?

Tags: linux, configuration

Help me beat my amnesia! Many moons ago I've used a tool that allowed me to capture manual (i.e. not done using Chef or Puppet) changes to a Linux system, store the information as a file and allow the system to be rebuilt later in this state atop a clean install.

Unfortunately I'm getting old and for the life of me can't remember which tool this was. It was something open source. Does anyone else remember?

Comment: Was it [checkinstall](https://www.debian-administration.org/article/147/Installing_packages_from_source_code_with_checkinstall) ?

Answer (score 0):

Is Tripwire the tool you are thinking of?

By the way Puppet can notify you when a file it manages had been changed.

Comment: Nah, Tripwire has more of a IDS angle, whereas the tool in thinking of was meant to ease the pain of snowflake servers.

Answer (score 0):

Is it etckeeper? https://joeyh.name/code/etckeeper/

> etckeeper is a collection of tools to let /etc be stored in a git,
>   mercurial, darcs, or bzr repository. It hooks into apt (and other
>   package managers including yum and pacman-g2) to automatically commit
>   changes made to /etc during package upgrades. It tracks file metadata
>   that revison control systems do not normally support, but that is
>   important for /etc, such as the permissions of /etc/shadow. It's quite
>   modular and configurable, while also being simple to use if you
>   understand the basics of working with revision control.